# EF Core Navigation FK value changed, notify property changed not called

Tags: entity-framework-core, inotifypropertychanged

Not sure how this "should" work with ef core: when a navigation fk value is updated, want a notify property event so the UI sees the selected FK entity.

Entity Classes

```
public partial class TblTemplate : ObservableValidator
{
   public Guid? TemplateFk 
   { 
       get => _pTemplateFk; 
       set => SetProperty(ref _pTemplateFk, value, true); 
   }
   private Guid? _pTemplateFk;

   [ForeignKey(nameof(TemplateFk))]
   [InverseProperty(nameof(TblTemp.TblTemplate))]
   public virtual TblTemp TemplateFkNavigation { get; set; }

}

public partial class TblTemp : ObservableValidator
{
  [Key]
  public Guid TempId { get => _pTempId; set => SetProperty(ref _pTempId, value, true); }
  private Guid _pTempId;

  [Required]
  public string TempDesc { get => _pTempDesc; set => SetProperty(ref _pTempDesc, value, true); }
  private string _pTempDesc;

  [InverseProperty("TemplateFkNavigation")]
  public virtual ICollection<TblTemplate>  TblTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

xaml

data grid is a list of viewSource and sets the "currentRow" which is referenced by the ComboBox.

combo box is used to update TemplateFK value for CurrentRow.

problem: the change to viewsource TemplateFkNavigation.TempDesc is not seen by the data grid column. (the entity value for TemplateFK is changed)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TempCellTemplate">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TemplateFkNavigation.TempDesc, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataGrid x:Name="PrimaryDataGrid"
  ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSource}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentRow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  >
 <DataGridTemplateColumn
    Header="Temp" 
    CellTemplate="{StaticResource TempCellTemplate}" 
    />
</DataGrid>

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="TempViewSource"
  Source="{Binding Path=Temps}"
  />

<StackPanel
  DataContext="{Binding CurrentRow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
>
<ComboBox x:Name="editTemp"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TempViewSource}}" 
  SelectedValuePath="TempId"
  SelectedValue="{Binding TemplateFk, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
  NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
/>
</StackPanel>
```

Question: how "should" the notify property change be raised so that the change to viewsource.TemplateFkNavigation.TempDesc is seen?

EDIT

Not sure if the problem is with the xaml binding or with the entity raising the notify property changed.

EDIT 2:

EF Core (proxy lazy load?) seems to update the property "TemplateFkNavigation" via the backing field not the "Set".

code change to Set; on TemplateFk change, TemplateFkNavigation.Set is never called, but the value for _templateFkNavigation is updated.

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(TemplateFk))]
[InverseProperty(nameof(TblRole.TblTemplate))]
public virtual TblRole TemplateFkNavigation 
{ 
get => _templateFkNavigation; 
set => SetProperty(ref _templateFkNavigation, value); 
}
private TblTemp _templateFkNavigation;
```

so, I must be doing something wrong with the proxy/lazyload.

using the EF Core Power Tools to generate the dbcontext, etc. I presume their generated code is correct.

EDIT 3:

if I scroll the grid so the changed record is not visible then scroll the record back into view, the value for TemplateFkNavigation.TempDesc is shown correctly.

to me, this indicates the backing field was updated but the property changed notification was not raised.

Comment: How does this relate to entity framework? This seems like a standard two-way binding question. Am I missing something?

Comment: the EF Core Proxy manages the lazy load of the FkNavigation property.

Comment: Hi! Were you able to find a solution to this problem? I've run up against the exact same issue.

Comment: no i did not. resolve the problem. I got squirreled by other issues. I basically was "hoping" a new version of core would have different behaviour or have a different notification method to help with this.